# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS. What's the best method?

Tags: linux, apache, http, mod-rewrite, https

I've searched high and low for a good answer to this question so any help is greatly appreciated.

I have an Linux server with apache, and I'm trying to understand what specific methods are available to accept HTTP requests and forward or redirect them to HTTPS on the same server.

I also need to know WHY one method might be better than another, why would you choose a specific method over another? This is quite important for me to understand.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Apache+PHP there are a couple different ways: server configuration or PHP code.  The benefits of performing this kind of check in the server configuration is that it will be applied everywhere, or only on a per-directory basis without having to change the PHP on every page in that folder or on your site.  The server configuration also provides faster runtime.

**Server Configuration**

Using mod_rewrite, you could add the following lines to your VHost config file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Obviously, mod_rewrite must be enabled on your server for this to work.  [Apache's mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) has more details.

**PHP Code**

As others have mentioned, PHP provides a `header` function that can be used to set the `Location` HTTP response header, and redirect the client to HTTPS.  This does not require access to the server configuration or mod_rewrite.

Comment: this is really helpful. Thanks! I wonder if you could clear a couple things up for me - you could add that code to the .htaccess file as well instead of the httpd.conf (which I think you mean by vhost config file?). My instinct is to steer clear of the .htaccess file. What do you think? Another thing I am interested in your opinion on is the difference between using mod_alias and mod_rewrite in this context? Again, my instinct would be to go with mod_rewrite because it can generally do more and would perhaps be better practice?

Comment: You could put this kind of code into an .htaccess file, but the syntax is a little different (more like mod_alias).  The problem there is I don't know of a way to do the HTTPS check in mod_alias or an .htaccess file, so I would definitely go with mod_rewrite for this application.

Comment: You can make those code changes in the httpd.conf file or in the configuration files that are virtual-host specific (if you are running multiple sites on a single server).

Comment: ok, so if you added those code changes in the httpd.conf file would it essentially cover ALL websites on the server? Also, would adding the code in either types of file ensure that the whole website would be https or just the landing page? A friend of mine seems to think that using a vhost would only redirect for the landing page and not other pages?

Comment: Putting it in the VHost configuration would cover that entire site unless you wrapped it in a <Directory> directive.  Putting the configuration in the httpd.conf file would cover all the sites unless it was put in a similar container (<Directory>, <Location>, etc).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much, you have been an enormous help! I wish I'd asked this sooner rather than pulling my hair out trying to trawl through Apache's documentation and such!

Answer (score -1):

Well, assuming you're using PHP, what I do is:

`header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 301);`

but there are many other ways, all depending on what you're working with at the time.  I'm sure someone will have a better answer then mine.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Outsider! Why would you pick this over the server config option?

Comment: @Luca: In my case, I work on several websites for my school, and the system admin has locked write access to the server config file.  I'm not 100% as to why he hasn't made the change, but that's a different story all together. :)